# Sloooow garbage collection query

Tags: mysql, performance

I have two tables, one stores user sessions and the other stores shopping cart data. `sessions` has a cart_id column which matches the corresponding `id` in the `carts` table. I am trying to run garbage collection on my database-based sessions. First I delete sessions that are expired:

```
DELETE FROM sessions WHERE expires < NOW();
```

Then, I delete carts that are now orphaned, in other words, there is no session whose cart_id matches this one.

```
DELETE `carts`
FROM `carts`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `sessions`
ON `carts`.`id` = `sessions`.`cart_id`
WHERE `sessions`.`cart_id` IS NULL
```

This last query is really slow, like more than 60 seconds kind-of-slow.

I've tried this one instead:

```
DELETE `cart`
FROM `cart`
WHERE `cart`.`id` NOT IN (SELECT `cart_id` FROM `sessions`)
```

Which is also slow. Any pointers?

Comment: Do you have an index on `sessions.cart_id` ?

Comment: I do not have an index. That's probably my problem, eh? *sheepishly retreats to read manual on indexes*

Comment: You definitely need indexes on columns you (regularly) use for joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your sessions.expires and sessions.cart_id columns are indexed.

If you have a high-traffic site and are adding a lot of carts/sessions, then your delete operation will be slower due to concurrency.

The last operation you posted will always be very slow if you have a lot of session (the IN close will need to compare each id one by one.)

A rule of thumb when using the IN statement: IN values count should be relatively small.

Comment: His query is fine. Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: the MySQL delete query specification ( `DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE] FROM tbl_name` ...) does not list the table name before the FROM statement.

Comment: Oh, my bad ypercube, just saw i didn't specify which query I was refering to in the answer.

Comment: Did you read (on the link you provided) the 2nd version, tagged **Multiple-table syntax** ?

Comment: I found it didn't work with this syntax and this reference article http://www.perturb.org/display/743_MySQL_Delete_with_a_LEFT_JOIN.html

Comment: Yes, but in this case the two queries are not deleting within multiple tables.

Comment: Okay, removed the delete query using the single table syntax.

Comment: Your last statements about the `IN` is also not exact, mainly because the OP does not use `IN` but `NOT IN`. These two (`IN` and `NOT IN`) operators have different optimizations in MySQL.

Comment: The select subquery in the IN statement will still produce a large resultset the NOT IN statement will have to parse.

Answer (score 2):

You could turn it around. Let each **cart** reference a **session id** via a [FOREIGN KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) and set `ON DELETE CASCADE`. That way when you delete a row in **session** the carts that are associated with it also gets deleted.

```
CREATE TABLE session (session_id INT NOT NULL,
                      expires DATE NOT NULL,
                     PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
                     INDEX expires_index (expires)
) ENGINE=INNODB;                          

CREATE TABLE cart (id INT, 
                   session_id INT,
                   INDEX session_index (session_id),
                   FOREIGN KEY (session_id) REFERENCES session(session_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

If you find that it takes too much time to delete all expired **carts** do smaller deletes more often with **limit**.

```
DELETE FROM session WHERE expires < NOW() ORDER BY expires LIMIT 10;
```